# Why 5 is greater than 10 python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bag

```
while True:
    x = input().split()
    if len(x) != 2:
        continue
    a, b = x
    if a > b:
        print(a, 'is greater than', b)
```

Hi, why when i input: '5 10', output: '5 is greater than 10'?

Comment: "5" is greater than "10" in a string comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in python all that's returned from `input` are strings, and they are still strings even after you use `split()` on them. `'5'` (the string) is larger than `'10'` (the string) because string comparison works on the first letter first!

To do it properly, convert them both to `int`:

```
while True:
    x = input().split()
    if len(x) != 2:
        continue
    a, b = x
    if int(a) > int(b):
        print(a, 'is greater than', b)
```

Answer (score 0):

In string comparison, do this instead.

```py
x = list(map(int, input().split()))
```