# Why is no output displayed using the following code and __name__ == "__main__?

Tags: python

Why does `loop_print()` produce no output when run in a command prompt, `python loops.py 5 10`?

```
import sys

def loop_print(arg1, arg2): # print series between arg1 and arg2
    """Print a series of numbers."""

    while arg1 < arg2:
        print(arg1, end=' ')
        arg1 += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop_print(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: `sys.argv[i]` is always a string.

Comment: Because `'5'` is greater than `'10'`. Strings are ordered lexicographically.

Comment: [Why 5 is greater than 10 python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58531100/why-5-is-greater-than-10-python)

Comment: Implicit type casting is so bad...

Answer (score 0):

You've got no output because `sys.argv` is an array of `str`. In other words: '5' < '10'? False. It never enters inside the while loop.
You must do a cast:

```py
...
loop_print(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
```

Comment: btw There is no `casting` in python. Your example is of a conversion.